# How can I customize the compile command?

Tags: compilation, commands

In one of my projects I need to run `make package install` when building instead of `make`. It remembers the last compile command I used, but resets to `make -k` every time emacs starts up. How can I customize `M-x compile` to default to `make package install`?

Comment: What's the value of `compilation-read-command`? If this variable is set to a non-`nil` value, `M-x compile` should prompt you for the compilation command to use. Alternatively, you can do `C-u M-x compile`; in this case, you will be prompted for the command regardless of the value of `compilation-read-command`.

Comment: It's set to t. It does allow me to edit the command before running, but I'd like to change what it defaults to

Comment: I see. Posted the comment above before checking the edit you made to your question ;)

Comment: A good question. From the manual, I had the impression that one can add "compile: ..." or "compile-command: ..." in the "Local Variables:" section at the end of a file, but my new Emacs doesn't seem to pay any attention to them... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the variable `compile-command` to change the compilation command that is used by default:

```el
(setq compile-command "make package install")
```

Comment: Note that the first time you run a compile command that *is not* `make package install`, that new command will become your new default.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to customize the variable per project rather than globally. You can use [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html). These allow you to apply certain customizations only for files in certain directory and its subdirectories.

So for example you want to use the `make package install` as compile command **only** in project A, you will need to create a file named `.dir-locals.el` in root directory of the project and add something like the following

```
((nil . ((compile-command . "make package install"))))
```

The syntax is explained in detail in the link to emacs manual above. As pointed out by @hatschipuh, you can use the commands `add-dir-local-variable` and `delete-dir-local-variable` to easily add and delete dir local values.

Comment: For convenience there are the commands `add-dir-local-variable` and `delete-dir-local-variable`.

Comment: @hatschipuh, good suggestion updated the answer to mention these commands

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the compile command per file here is an example:

```
---
title: Svadhyaya
---

Svadhyaya (Sanskrit: स्वाध्याय svādhyāya m.; *self-study*) is one of the five
Niyamas (Sanskrit: नियम niyama m.; *commandments*, *restrictions*, 
*ethical rules*, *code of conduct* in Patanjalis Yogasutra). The word is 
made up of Sva (*self*, *belonging to me*) and Adhyaya (*investigation*,
*exploration*) together.

<!--
Local Variables:
mode: markdown
coding: utf-8-unix
compile-command: (string-join
    (list "pandoc" "-s" (buffer-file-name) "-o"
        (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".html")) " ")
End:
-->
```

That looks a bit awkward, but this way no dependencies to other files that may control the compilation exist (*Makefile*, *CMakeLists.txt*... not even your personal dot-emacs). So you can send the file out or unpack it years later and compile it should still work.

[File-Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html)